# How do you filter matrix blocks by type?

Tags: templating, matrix, forloop

Is there a way to filter a matrix by block type, or get a count of how many items there are of a certain type? Can't find a syntax example.

I created a matrix with two blocks. In pseudo code, basically what I want to do is this:

```
{% set typeOneBlocks = theMatrix blocks where type == "typeOne" %}

{% if typeOneBlocks != null %}
    <div class="divAWrapper">
        {% for block in typeOneBlocks %}
            <div class="divA">{# do stuff #}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Same with `typeTwo` blocks. If there are no items of one type or the other, I don't want to create that container and have it sitting empty.

If there is not a way to filter or get a count, I'd have to use for loops to increment vars for how many of each block type there are and then act based on those counts. Seems there should be a simpler way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can grab a specific block type in Matrix by doing this:

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField.type('typeOne') %}
    {{ block.text | markdown }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you wanted to know the number of blocks of a certain type, you can do:

```
{% set blocks = entry.myMatrixField.type('typeOne') %}
{{ blocks | length }}
```

If you want to search for multiple block types, you can do this:

```
{% set blocks = entry.myMatrixField.type('typeOne, typeTwo') %}
```

For your specific example, it would look like this:

```
{% set typeOneBlocks = entry.myMatrixField.type('typeOne') %}

{% if typeOneBlocks | length %}
    <div class="divAWrapper">
        {% for block in typeOneBlocks %}
            <div class="divA">{# do stuff #}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: 6 minutes for a reply? Seriously, you guys are amazing. I'm not sure if I missed the documentation or if you just added it, but thanks for the quick help. http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields

Comment: It's been in the docs for awhile. :)

Comment: @BradBell I 'd like to filter matrix block by category field. could you please guide for the same.

Answer (score 1):

In my Case i had to add .all() at the end then it worked with the Verison
"Craft Solo 4.1.4.1"